# Splitting up an array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I made a 12x12 array but i have some problems making the array do what i want, i want to split the array into 1 value for the first place in the array for example. So that i can then make it more understandable for me.I know it's more difficult but for me it seems simpler. It's for a board for a game by the way.

MY ARRAY:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class PlayingArea {
private String letters;
public char[][] grid;
public PlayingArea(String letters) {
    this.letters = letters;
}
public void populate() {
    int n = letters.length();
    grid = new char[12][12];

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            grid[i][j] = letters.charAt(r.nextInt(n));
        }
    }
}

public String gridAsString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char[] letterRow : grid) {
        sb.append(Arrays.toString(letterRow)).append('\n');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

```
        System.out.println("How many random letters to choose from would you like (3,4)");
    String letters = "";
    while (letters.length() < 4) {
        int region = input.nextInt();
        if (region == 4) {
            letters = "EFGH";
        } else if (region == 3) {
                letters = "EFG";
            } else {
                System.out.println("You inputed a wrong value, try again...");
            }
        }
public class Cell {
    cell = new char[c];
    if (regions == 4) {
        c = (char)(r.nextInt(4) + 'E';
     }
    if (regions == 3) {
        c = (char)(r.nextInt(3) + 'E';
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any 2-d array here. What is your question?

Comment: Also, what does "split the array into 1 value for the first place in the array" mean? Example input, example output.

Comment: I mean so that i can then compare the values as individuals...

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that arrays are probably not the best abstraction for your data.  What do I mean by this?  Let me try to make this more concrete:

I have a one-dimensional array.  The "contract" for this array is as follows:

- index position 0: the currently used array length (or, the number of values in active use)
- index position 1: the currently selected value in the array (absolute position)
- index positions 2 thru 101: data space

The code that you write based on this contract will lack conciseness, will probably not be self-documenting and will be error-prone.  No run-time error will occur if an attempt is made to gather data from a miscomputed index position 1 (intended to contain metadata).

A vastly superior abstraction for this contract is to write a class instead of trying to make everything work in the array:

```
class DataVector {
    private static final int MAX_VECTOR_SIZE = 100;

    private int dataLength;
    private int selectedPos;
    private int[] values;

    public DataVector() {
        dataLength = 0;
        selectedPos = -1; // by default, no data is selected
        values = new int[MAX_VECTOR_SIZE - 1];
    }

    :
    :
 }
```

Not only can you then write methods which make your code much easier to understand and easier to read (methods such as `setSelectedPositionTo(int pos)` but your app is less fragile.  If you need to create a data structure based on this simple model such as a grid, that is easy too ... an array might be suitable for this:

```
DataVector[] myGrid = new DataVector[GAME_GRID_SIZE];  // creates array object
for (DataVector dv : myGrid) dv = new DataVector();    // initializes array with
                                                       // new DataVector objects
```

Accessing the data may be as easy as using a method you've written for DataVector, such as:

```
int currValue = myGrid[selectedRow].getValue(position);
```

TL;DR: If you are using arrays to describe more than one kind of data, then you will probably benefit greatly by breaking out the kinds of data and writing a custom value class.  This is what object oriented programming is all about.